# How can I calculate the area in which two cuboids faces make contact?

Tags: 3d, contacts, area

I am designing a 3D packing algorithm for cuboids items, and in order to adjust it correctly, I need to be able to calculate the area created where two cubids touch each other.
What I mean by that is that I want to be able to calculate the "connection area" in which those two cubids rectengle faces make contact, or in other words, the area where those two cuboids touch each other.

A cubid item is defined by its :

- dimensions: int width, int height, int depth
- startingPosition: int x, int y, int z

You can assume that there isnt any rotation going on inside this system, and that all variables are whole numbers.

Any help in calculating this area will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend upon the language and such that you are using it also depends upon the origin on the cuboid.  Assuming it is in a corner, lets say the bottom left back corner is the origin, this will allow us to add along axis.

Lets put cube1s x,y,z in cube1_pos and cube1_pos2 for the opposite corner, this also sets the size.  The same can go for cube2

```
cube1_pos = [x,y,z];
cube1_pos2 = [x_s,y_s,z_s];
cube2_pos = [x2,y2,z2];
cube2_pos2 = [x2_s,y2_s,z2_s];
```

We can then look at instances where all points between cube1_pos and cube1_pos2 and see if cube2 is in any of those points  This could be used for volume, but since objects can't go into each other it will find area.

You simply check if they collide range-wise then subtract them and get absolute value of each property and multiply it all together.  I can go into more detail if you request.